# What exception is thrown on database access issue

Tags: java, sql-server, database, spring-boot, exception

I m using a SQL Server database  with springboot.
I want to handle database access issue (if the database becomes inaccessible for some reason, I want to catch the exception thrown).

In my local environment I'm using Docker SQL Server database from this image 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest'. And when the database is inaccessible just before my query, I get the [JDBCConnectionException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/exception/JDBCConnectionException.html)

In my preprod environment, to my great surprise, I get the exception [SqlServerException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/sqlserverexception-class?view=sql-server-ver15).
The only differences between my local and preprod env are:

- in local I use SQL Server Docker container (so to simulate database access issue, I stop the container)
- in preprod env, I'm using Azure SQL database in cloudfoundry. So I just unbind the database from my app to simulate database access issue.

So what exception might I catch to be sure to handle database inaccessible issue?

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  Repository repository;

  public void getDataFromBd(){
    try {
      repository.findAllData();
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
      log.error("The database is inaccessible");
      processDatabaseInaccessible(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since connections to different SQL instances are throwing different exceptions it makes sense to have a `catch` block for each:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  Repository repository;

  public void getDataFromBd(){
    try {
      repository.findAllData();
    }
    catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
      log.error("The database is inaccessible");
      processDatabaseInaccessible(e);
    }
    catch (SqlServerException e) {
      log.error("The database is inaccessible");
      processDatabaseInaccessible(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Personally I'd also put a generic exception catch block in there as well.

Comment: that's sure to fix the problem. But how can I be sure that another scenario does not cause an exception other than SqlServerException and JDBCConnectionException  ? What is the most generic exception thrown when database is inaccessible ?

Comment: Your local and Azure instances appear to be using either different drivers or different connection methods (or both) which are throwing different exceptions. In terms of a generic exception, the closest common one is `Exception` which is the most generic you can get.